# Integration by substitution in $n$ dimension

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I just read the proof of Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality abaout fractional integral operator. Then I found the following identity (but don't understand it)

\begin{equation}
\int_{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}\backslash B\left( x,R\right) }\frac{1}{\left\vert x-y\right\vert
^{c(n-1)}}dy=\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{R}^{\infty }\frac{1}{r^{^{c(n-1)}}}%
r^{n-1}drd\sigma 
\end{equation}
where $B(x,R)$ denote $n$ dimensional ball, centered on $x$ and radius $R$. I guess that identity is generalization of substitution formula. Could you help me to understand that identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left integral is over all of space except the ball.  $y$ is a point outside the ball and ranges over the volume of integration.  $|x-y|$ is the distance between the points.  The right integral is changing to spherical coordinates.  $r$ is the distance between $x$ and $y$, so $r=|x-y|$.  The inner integral is over the radius, and ranging from $R$ to $\infty$ avoids the ball nicely.  $d\sigma$ represents all the angular variables ($n-$1 of them).  The $r^{n-1}$ factor represents the radial variation of the surface area of an $n-1$ sphere.  Presumably the next thing to happen is to do the $d\sigma$ integral getting the surface of the $n-1$ sphere ($4\pi$, for example, if $n=3$).

Comment: Singular variable in 2 dimension means the angle?

Comment: @beginner:  I'm not sure what singular variable you mean, but in 2 dimensions the area element is $r\;dr\; d\theta$.  The $r$ is $r^{2-1}$, the $dr$ you see, and $d\theta$ is the $d\sigma$.  In 3 dimensions it is $r^2\; dr\; \sin \theta\; d\theta\; d\phi$ with $\sin \theta\; d\theta\; d\phi$ being $d\sigma$

Comment: Do u know any book/references that can explain this substitution in detail and rigorous way?

Comment: @beginner:  Sorry, no.  Maybe somebody else does.

Comment: @beginner:  In my example above, whether the factor is $\sin \theta$ or $\cos \theta$ depends whether you measure up from the $xy$ plane (sin) or down from $z$ (cos).  The idea is the same, but I think down from $z$ is more standard.